# How to add blocking IP rules on each nginx-ingress host

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have searched a lot and I didn't find the solution. I want to block/allow ip's into each host definition in the nginx-ingress, not per locations.

This is the ingress.yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test1.test.com
    #Blocking rules here, only affecting test1.test.com domain
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: wordpressA
          servicePort: 80
  - host: test2.test.com
    #Blocking rules here, only affecting test2.test.com domain
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: wordpressB
          servicePort: 80
```

Many thanks for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to split those `host` definitions into separate `ingress` rules.

Then you can use annotation to [whitelist source range](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/87d1b8bbf28265386b339e65d8943d8c3f8582ed/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#whitelist-source-range) using following `annotation` :
`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range`

Something like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app1-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "10.0.0.0/24"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app1.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: app1-service
          servicePort: http
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app2-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "10.0.0.0/24"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app2.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: app2-service
          servicePort: http
```

You can also use [server snipper](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/87d1b8bbf28265386b339e65d8943d8c3f8582ed/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#server-snippet) and add nginx config to the `yaml`.

Something like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
location / {
  # block one workstation
  deny    192.168.1.1;
  # allow anyone in 192.168.1.0/24
  allow   192.168.1.0/24;
  # drop rest of the world 
  deny    all;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I seen this config before (using diferent ingress) but we want to use only one ingress, both solutions need different Ingress definitions. Is this the only way?

Comment: Splitting ingress rules, will it use the same LB ingress?

Comment: As far as I'm aware this is the only solution. What LB are you using, is it cloud or MLB?

Comment: Hi @Crou, thanks, I use cloud LB. And yes, I tried splitting configs and it's all ok.
Many thanks!

Comment: And just FYI: If you're using HAProxy for your ingress (and not nginx like OP asks about), there is a similar `whitespace` annotation: `haproxy.org/whitelist: "192.168.1.0/24, 192.168.2.100"`. See [Ingress Options # whitelist | HAProxy Kubernetes Ingress Controller documentation](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/kubernetes/latest/configuration/ingress/#whitelist)